# What sentence is more correct? I go to a dancing class to improve my skills or I go to dancing classes

Tags: grammaticality

I go to a dancing class to improve my skills.

Or

I go to dancing classes to improve my dance skill.

Comment: Among other things, _class_ can mean both _a course of instruction_ and _an individual lesson_, so you can use either singular or plural. Presumably dancing involves more than one skill, so I would probably make that plural.

Answer (score 1):

Both "I go to a dancing class" and "I go to dancing classes" are completely correct. They have very similar, but slightly different, meanings.

As [Kate Bunting](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/104866/kate-bunting) pointed out in a comment, the word "class" can mean either a course of instruction (in other words, a series of lessons), or one individual lesson.

"I go to a dancing class" means that there is some course of instruction in dancing, and I attend that course of instruction from time to time.

"I go to dancing classes" could mean either of two things. It could mean that there are several individual dancing lessons that occur from time to time, and I attend some of those lessons. Alternatively, it could mean that there are several courses of instruction in dancing, and from time to time, I attend one of the courses of instruction.

As for the second half of the sentence, I would use either "my dancing skills", or just "my skills" (because it's obvious that I mean my dancing skills). For some reason, the word "skills" is usually used in the plural even when you're really talking about just one skill, and so you shouldn't say "my dancing skill". Finally, it doesn't sound right to say "my dance skills" instead of "my dancing skills"; the word before "skills" is usually a gerund (but it can be a different kind of noun instead).